# d3js selection.enter() depends on the order of new added data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Do I understand it wrong? or it is supposed to be that way?

Original circle

```
d3.select("svg").selectAll('circle')
.data([{'name':'john', 'age': '50'}]).enter().append('circle')
.attr("cx", function(d){return d.age;}).attr("cy", '200').attr("r", '10').attr("fill",    'red');
```

on click buttonA called below function

```
function prependValue(){
    d3.select("svg").selectAll('circle')
    .data([{'name':'peter', 'age': '100'}, {'name':'john', 'age': '50'} ])
    .enter().append('circle').attr("cx", function(d){return d.age;}).attr("cy", '200').attr("r", '10').attr("fill", 'green');
}
```

I'm supposing it should add a green circle at cx = 100 for peter, however, it change the color of the circle for john to green.

If i do

```
.data([{'name':'john', 'age': '50'}, {'name':'peter', 'age': '100'} ])
```

everything works as expected.

Comment: I'm glad you got an answer to your question, but you need to put in a little more effort at making your questions more understandable, without relying on others to edit them for you.  In particular, several of your questions show problems with code formatting.  There is help available above the Markdown editor that explains how to format code properly; you should familiarize yourself with this process before asking your next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify a function to use for matching data elements (the optional argument to `.data()`), D3 matches elements by their index. That is, it indeed assumes that you will pass elements in the same order.

To prevent this, pass in a function that tells it how to match elements (e.g. by name). See [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here I quoted Mike's answer for this question on google group in case anyone wonders how the join works:
"
You need to specify a key function if you want to join by name. 
Otherwise the default behavior is to join by index.

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/ 
  https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data

Mike "